# How to send base64 pdf code as attachment through nodemailer/mailgun in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, base64, nodemailer

I've tried all the stack codes I've found here:

```
            filename: 'my-file.pdf',
            content:  Buffer('base64code', 'base64'),

            contentType: 'application/pdf'
```

```
filename: 'your.pdf',
content: 'encodedpdfstring', //EncodedString
encoding: 'base64'
```

Etc, but nothing works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will work for you or not, I was using SendGrid. And this is how I did.
I first utilize the [html-pdf-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node) npm package to generate pdfBuffer out of HTML code.

```
let file = { content: emailTemplate };
let options = { format: "A4" };
const pdfBuffer = await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options);
```

And then, SENDGRID.send method to basically send an email, with body content and pdf as an attachment

```
await SENDGRID.send({
      from,
      to,
      html,
      subject,
      attachments: [
        {
          content: pdfBuffer.toString("base64"),
          filename: filename,
          type: "application/pdf",
          disposition: "attachment",
        },
      ],
    });
```

Properties I passed above are:

> ```
> From(email) - from whom
> to(email) - to whom
> html - the body content as an HTML code
> subject - email subject
> filename - filename of the attachment e.g. my_file.pdf
> ```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I ended up sending the pdfBytes, coz nodemailder accepts it. I didn't use sendgrid coz I cant create an account!